# Invalid chai property jsonschema

Tags: mocha.js, chai, web-api-testing

I'm working on the API automation using mocha and chai.

I need to compare the response of the api and compare it with chai jsonschema assertion.

```
expect(response).to.be.jsonSchema(expectedResponse)
```

I get the following error,

```
 Error: Invalid Chai property: jsonSchema
      at Object.proxyGetter [as get] (node_modules\chai\lib\chai\utils\proxify.js:78:17)
      at _callee2$ (test\/ServerEndPointsTest.js:70:21)
      at tryCatch (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:22)
      at Generator.next (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:119:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: Which chai plugin do you use?

Comment: Chai plugin from my package.json
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "chai-json-schema": "^1.5.1",

Comment: How did you use `chai-json-schema`? Show the minimal, reproducible code example

Comment: response = res.body
expect(response).to.be.jsonSchema(expectedResponse.GetCCAccounts.with)

ExpectedResponse.js
var expectedResponse = {

    GetCCAccounts: {
        "with":{
                      "response": {
            "code": '0303',
            "desc": 'Invalid session token.'
        },
        "httpCode": 400
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned the imports of your test file and most likely that is the place where you are making a mistake.

These sorts of errors are thrown by the chai library when you try to use something which is not in-built in your case the chai-json-schema plugin.

Try to update your imports as below:

```
const {expect} = require("chai").use(require('chai-json-schema'));
```

This will add the required methods of the chai plugin to your expect object.